# Can I see the RAID group name for my SQL Server Database files?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, storage

Is it possible to see the RAID group name that my database (and log) files are sitting on, in one of the DMVs (or some other system table) ?

Comment: You can see the drive letter, as I am sure you know, but there is no way from within SQL to see the underlying RAID group information. You would have to go look at the tools on your OS/storage solution to see that level of information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL Server doesn't have any access to anything that low level.  Typically Windows can't even see the RAID group information given that each hardware vendor stores that differently and typically exposing that information to the OS doesn't have any benefit.  You'll need to work with your hardware team to make the drive labels match, but even then that isn't exposed within SQL Server.  You would need to use PowerShell or WMI to pull that information from the OS.

Answer (score 0):

One way to work around the visibility issue is to mount RAID volumes under a folder, with each mounted foler having a name that matches the RAID volume name. You (or your ops team) will have to assure these mappings are correct, but once you've established this practice any time you see the name in the path to a file in SQL Server or the OS, you're going to see the name of the RAID volume right in the path.